# C# Autohide form

Tags: c#, winforms

I've a winforms app that "docks" to the taskbar
I'd like to autohide the form and make it appear only when the mouse goes near/over the form

any suggestions ?

Comment: my suggestion: use wpf instead of winforms. makes stuff like this cake. ;)

Comment: I have no idea how you dock something and then hide it.  Use a NotifyIcon, that's the standard user interface for apps that "run in the tray".  It however requires a click on the icon to initiate any action.  Hovering cannot be made to work.  Not a problem, users are used to clicking on them.

Comment: waiting for wpf to mature with 4.0 first !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install a global hook onto the mouse-move event and check to see if it is within the form boundaries. Should work even with the form hidden. If not just store the location as a rectangle and check against that.

Code for a simple and handy global hook implementation can be found at:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx

I've used this method to create "hotspot" functionality to a user desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is exactly answering your question, but there is a sample of this on Codeplex...

http://remoteaccessmonitor.codeplex.com/

Browse the source code and check out the MinimizeToTray.cs file - it has examples of pop up messages when hiding and I think its default behaviour is to re-appear on click (although I imagine this could be changed).

Comment: quite different scenario i'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

You could.

- Poll mouse coords until it's within a certain radius of your app.
- Position an invisible, always-on-top form above the docked app and have it fire a MouseEnter event.

That's all I can think of really. Either.

Comment: hmm, I'd prefer to avoid polling, positioning an invisible form might work but would it not obstruct clicking the real estate below as well ?